# Timetable week view in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a week view of a timetable.
I don't want a calendar week but I want a week like in school.
The data (events and description) need to be variable, not constant.
A method to get a view similar to the one in the following picture would be great, a simpler one would be appreciated too.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You may use [calendar_view](https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_view) package. You can achieve your output by using week view mentioned in the package.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can I use this with one week (no switching between weeks) too? Or any good alternatives?